# How to align bulma navbar burger to right end of the page?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I am trying to add navbar using bulma css , am new to css  couldn't understand why the navburger span is aligning below logo image and not the far end adjacent to the logo. Am using the code with some js toggle active presented in bulma navbar examples here. (https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/)

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NewApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.0/css/bulma.min.css">
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    <style>
        .navbar-item.is-mega {
  position: static;

  .is-mega-menu-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: .375rem 1rem;
  }
}

      #a { grid-area: a; }
#b { grid-area: b; }
#c { grid-area: c; }
#d { grid-area: d; }
#e { grid-area: e; }

#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "a a a a"
        "b c d e";

    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 512px) {
    #grid {
        grid-template-areas:
            "a a a"
            "b c d"
            "e e e";
    }
}

.center, .center-column, .top, .right, .bottom, .left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.center-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top    { align-items:     flex-start; }
.right  { justify-content: flex-end;   }
.bottom { align-items:     flex-end;   }
.left   { justify-content: flex-start; }

.single-spaced, .single-spaced * {
    line-height: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet>
<app-header></app-header>
</router-outlet>
```

header.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar is-transparent">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" alt="Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox" width="112" height="28">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbarExampleTransparentExample">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarExampleTransparentExample" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
        <!-- FIXME: fix the href link.. -->
      <a class="navbar-item" href="https://localhost:4200/">
        Home
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <a class="navbar-link" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/">
          Docs
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/">
            Overview
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/modifiers/">
            Modifiers
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
            Columns
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/">
            Layout
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/">
            Form
          </a>
          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/box/">
            Elements
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item is-active" href="https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/">
            About me
            <div class="modal">
              <div class="modal-background"></div>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Any other Bulma elements you want -->
              </div>
              <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="field is-grouped">
          <p class="control">
              <!-- FIXME ; fix the href -->
            <a class="bd-tw-button button" data-social-network="Twitter" data-social-action="tweet" data-social-target="https://stakeradix.io" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=RadixDPOS: secure radix consensus through stake delegation &amp;hashtags=stakexrdwithmozhi&amp;url=https://stakeradix.io&amp;via=pspk__janasena">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </span>
              <span>
                Tweet
              </span>
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class="control">
              <!-- FIXME: Go to the official radix page -->
            <a class="button is-primary" target="_blank" href="https://www.radixdlt.com/">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <span>Explorer</span>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Expected:**
[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

Comment: Post the HTML and CSS you used and update your question

Comment: Try adding the class `navbar-end` to the navbar burger in header.component.html 
like this:

`<a class="navbar-burger burger navbar-end" data-target="navbarExampleTransparentExample">`